# How to search for a word in a variable in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, search, jira

I am trying to search for a specific word in variable comment in below code how to do search in nodejs. Comment is string of many words so i need to search for every word in comment and see if that matches my required word.

My nodejs Code:

```
   var jira = new JiraApi('https:', 'gec-jira.com', 8, 'user', 'pass', '2', true, false);

    jira.findIssue(id, function(error, issue) {


       var comment=JSON.stringify(issue.comment.comments);


     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RegExp` to find a word in string. Regular expression has word boundary (`\b`) metacharacter that can be used to find a word in a string. More on it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
var re =  new RegExp('\\b'+ word + '\\b','i')
var match = re.exec(comment)
```